# A selection made in a Rails 4 select_tag displays a blank instead what was selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's the code:

```
<%= select_tag pg.id, options_from_collection_for_select(@misc_options, :id, :name, pg.option_id), include_blank: true, ... %>
```

***UPDATE:***
I found that even though the blank option was displayed, when I pulled down the menu again, the selection that I made was checked... it just wasn't showing it as selected.

Comment: What is the result you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)

> Be sure to specify the same class as the value_method when specifying
>   selected or disabled options. Failure to do this will produce
>   undesired results. Example:
>
> options_from_collection_for_select(@people, 'id', 'name', '1') Will
>   not select a person with the id of 1 because 1 (an Integer) is not the
>   same as ‘1’ (a string)
>
> options_from_collection_for_select(@people, 'id', 'name', 1) should
>   produce the desired results.

So I guess your `:id` represents an integer and your `pg.option_id` is returning an string, or any other thing that doesn't match types.

Comment: thanks for taking a stab at it. However, the array is directly from the database and option_id is an integer.